# How to solve such equations involving probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, exponential-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am trying to understand how the equation (2) is obtained from the equation (1) that involves probability as shown in the following case:

$P_d = \text{Pr}\Bigl(h_d<h_e\Bigr)$  ----(1)

where $\text{Pr}$ denotes the probability, $h_d$ and $h_e$ are independent exponential random variables with variances $\sigma^2_{d}$ and $\sigma^2_{e}$ respectively.

$P_d = \frac{\sigma^2_e}{\sigma^2_e+\sigma^2_d}$  ----(2)

My query is how the equation (2) is obtained from equation (1).

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P_d=\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{y} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx \, \mu e^{-\mu y}dy$ where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are the parameters of the exponential  distributions of $h_d$ and $h_e$ respectively. Write down $\lambda $ and $\mu$ in terms of the variance and compute this integral.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer sir...but can you please specify  how the integration limits are obtained....

Comment: If you fix $h_e$ to be $y$ then $h_d$ ranges from $0$ to $y$ since we want $h_d <h_e$.  Basically we condition on $h_e$, write down the probability, multiply by the density of $h_e$ and integrate. @karu

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for such a precise solution and explanation....